# Find value, put it in an array and find the smallest value in the array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dynamic-arrays

I would like to find a given value in a range, and if I find the value I would like to put it in an array. After the loop I would like to give the smallest value in the array to a variable.

How is is possible?

```
    For k = 2 To LastRow_Roles
        If roles_sheet.Cells(k, 2).Value = "Admin" Then
            selected_number = roles_sheet.Cells(k, 1).Value
            ReDim aArray(0 To UBound(aArray) + 1) As Variant
            aArray(UBound(aArray)) = selected_number        
         end if
    next k

minimum_value = Application.min(aArray)
low_sheet.Cells(1, 1) = minimum_value
Erase aArray
ReDim aArray(0 To 1) As Variant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `ReDim Preserve` so that you're preserving the existing data that has been appended to the array.

You can then use the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min` function to extract the `Min` number found within the array.

```
For k = 2 To LastRow_Roles
    If roles_sheet.Cells(k, 2).Value = "Admin" Then
        ReDim Preserve aArray(0 To UBound(aArray) + 1)
        aArray(UBound(aArray)) = roles_sheet.Cells(k, 1).Value
    End If
Next k

minimum_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aArray)
low_sheet.Cells(1, 1) = minimum_value
Erase aArray
ReDim aArray(0 To 1) As Variant
```

Comment: thank you. Just one question. When I am using `Application.WorksheetFunction.max(aArray)` it gives back rounded value. I see only 66 intead of 66.4684. Can you please help me with this? I tried `Long` and `double` instead of `Variant` but it is not working.

Comment: what have you declared the variable you're assigning the maximum value to? If it's got decimal places it should be a double. `Dim max_value as Double`. Otherwise, debug and see if the array is populating with decimal values.

Comment: you are right. The `maximum_value` was `Long`. With `Double` is working like a charm.